# return categories ordered by article date

Tags: php, mysql, select, subquery

I've a website with blog articles. A post can have 1 or more categories. 
Now I want a query that returns a list of all categories, ORDERED BY the blogs article date.
I have experimented with a SELECT in a SELECT query, but that doesn't work... 
How can I do it and return the categories ordered by the article date?

table blogs:

```
|id------|title------------------|date------|
|1       |Test title             |2014-05-05|
|2       |Test title 2           |2014-04-01|
|3       |Last test title        |2014-02-02|
|4       |Another blog item      |2014-01-06|
```

table categories:

```
|id|category-----|
|1 |computers    |
|2 |home         |
|3 |work         |
```

table blogs_categories:

```
|blog_id|category_id|
|1      |1          |
|2      |1          |
|4      |2          |
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple join and select only distinct data from categories

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.*
FROM categories c
LEFT JOIN blogs_categories bc ON(c.id =bc.category_id)
LEFT JOIN blogs b ON(b.id=bc.blog_id)
ORDER BY b.date DESC
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8edb/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.*, 
       b.`date`
FROM categories as c
LEFT JOIN blogs_categories as bc on bc.category_id=c.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT `id`, max(`date`) as `date`
    FROM blogs
    GROUP BY `id`
) as b on b.`id`=bc.`blog_id`
GROUP BY c.`id`
ORDER BY b.`date` desc
```